# Tengo que crear un objeto PRODUCTO(id,nombre,costo) y crear un método que codifique los costos reemplazando del 1 al 0 a A ,J Ejemplo (15.80 = AE HJ))

Tags: oracle

He estado intentando esto pero solo consigo errores quizás haya otro metodo el cual estaría muy agradecido de recibir

```
IDproducto varchar (15),
Nombre Varchar (15),
Costo Varchar (15)
);
```

```
create or replace type body producto as member function codificador return number is resultado varchar
begin 
case Costo
when 1 then resultado:='A';
when 2 then resultado:='B';
when 3 then resultado:='C';
when 4 then resultado:='D';
when 5 then resultado:='E';
when 6 then resultado:='F';
when 7 then resultado:='G';
when 8 then resultado:='H';
when 9 then resultado:='I';
when 0 then resultado:='J';
end;
return resultado;

end 
end
```

está escrito en oracle19c

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Hola si solo es sustituir el numero indicado por una letra te recomiendo usar la funcion Traslate de Oracle.

:Costo es la variable

```
Select Translate(:Costo,'1234567890.','ABCDEFGHIJ ') FROM DUAL;
```

Ejemplo:

```
Select Translate(18.95,'1234567890.','ABCDEFGHIJ ') FROM DUAL;
```

Respuesta: AH IE

```
Select Translate(535.18,'1234567890.','ABCDEFGHIJ ') FROM DUAL;
```

Respuesta: ECE AH